# Make one word within sentence bigger in markdown

Tags: markdown

Within markdown, is there a way of making one word within a sentence bigger than all of the rest?

Know you can change the size of a heading using #'s but not sure if there is a way to change the size of the main body as a whole, let alone just one word within the main body?

Thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking, `#`s for headings do _not_ change text size. Hashes in Markdown represent headings, which get converted to `<h1>` through `<h6>` tags in the resulting HTML. These are semantic tags, not style tags. In many cases will result in larger text, but that's dependent on your document's styling (CSS, probably).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't do it strictly within markdown, but the markdown syntax does permit HTML markup, and many markdown processors honor that, at least partially. So the following would theoretically work, and might actually work depending on the processor.

```
This is a paragraph with one <span style="font-size:larger;">word</span>
larger than the others.
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work on GitHub. GitHub allows HTML but strips the "style" attribute. No custom styling for me.

Comment: See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) from the Mozilla MDN Web Docs for a more complete description of the sizing options available in HTML.

Comment: Doesn't work in Confluence with the Insert Markup->Markdown feature. Note: Inside a table.