# How to highlight text in Octopress

Tags: rubygems, markdown, octopress

How to highlight normal text in markdown file in Octopress?

I am not asking about code syntax highlight.

Is there some useful gem or plugin?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply Color in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465557/how-to-apply-color-in-markdown)

Comment: Another possible duplicate would be [Make one word within sentence bigger in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33596287/866026)