# Can I add larger Font text to the markdown widget on https://portal.azure.com dashboard?

Tags: azure, markdown, azureportal, azure-monitoring

In *https://portal.azure.com* I would like to make a dashboard with big labels.

The idea is that we'd get the stats on a big TV so we could see the state of our services at a glance. Big labels will make it [easier to consume](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/information-radiators/).

I'm trying to add larger than h1 [font](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_font.asp) to my [markdown](https://brokenco.de/2017/08/13/customizing-azure-dashboard.html) tiles but the inline CSS `<font size="8">Test env</font>` does not parse.

Does anyone know how to get this to work or if azure dashboards even support this?

[*Click here to see example of the text size I want (Top label added using paint) vs h1 (Bottom label added using h1 markup)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Rsm.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the scope of this question was just a markdown one!

The following works:

```
 <span style="font-size:200px;">CAT</span>
```

See:[Make one word within sentence bigger in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596287/make-one-word-within-sentence-bigger-in-markdown)