# Increasing text size in Azure Dashboard metrics

Tags: text-size, azure-dashboard

We've got a 4K 55" panel up on the wall in our support analyst room, been playing around with some better dashboard designs and hit upon something of a blocker. The text size in the metrics is too small to be legible from much more than a couple of feet away.

I was hunting around and did find this previous question about the labels:
[Can I add larger Font text to the markdown widget on https://portal.azure.com dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370013/can-i-add-larger-font-text-to-the-markdown-widget-on-https-portal-azure-com-da)

But I'm unclear on how I might apply that same logic to the text within the metrics. Specifically the grid displays.